# Reset required to ssh into my GCP VM instance

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying out GCP as an alternative to AWS. I've created an f1.micro with ubuntu 20.04 to mess around with. That worked fine. I could ssh into the vm from the dashboard, use gloud on the cli, and ssh directly after I exchanged keys.

That was yesterday. This morning I can't reach the vm at all. Not from the dashboard, gcloud or ssh. The dashboard shows the instance running, and that it has been running since yesterday. No log entries since yesterday. The vm has the same ip address.

If I reset the instance, everything works again.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you reset the SSH key.

I created an instance with  f1.micro with ubuntu 18.04 with SSH key, but it works now.
I will check it tomorrow to see if it works again.

Did you set any other configuration?

One day later: I can not see any issue.

Comment: I used the same personal ssh key all the way through. And I also couldn't ssh from the dashboard, which use it's own et of keys.

Comment: Did you try to connect via the [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh)?

Can you connect with using [third-party tools](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#thirdpartytools)?

Did you use for example [SSH with security keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/ssh-with-sk)?